# Telegram Bot: При нажатии на кнопку должен выдать новую кнопку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI. Ка сделать так, что бы при нажатии на InlineKeyboardButton бот выдавал сообщение с новыми InlineKeyboardButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InlineKeyboardButton, насколько я знаю, возвращает сообщение с заданным текстом в чат. Можно создать обработчик такого сообщения, который вернёт новую кнопку